# Count zeros in the series of N numbers - Java

Tags: java, regex

i want to count the number of zeros in a **N**-range of numbers starting from 0.

If the **N** is **100** means,then the range should starts from *0 to 100* then and the count should be **12**.

Below code works till some **10^6**

```
private static int calcZeros(String input){
        int count = 0;

        int n = Integer.parseInt(input);
        for(int i = 0;i<=n;i++){
            count += String.valueOf(i).replaceAll("[a-zA-Z_1-9]","").trim().length(); 
        }
        return count;
    }
```

If the **N** exceeds **10^6**, it hangs,Obiviously, for loop runs for long duration.

My Question here is ,this is right approach to find the zeros count?

Suggest me some fastest way to do the count.

Comment: replaceAll is very slow if you use it a lot. Try a mathematical approach like @assylias is suggesting

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count number of 0s from \[1,2,....num\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614288/count-number-of-0s-from-1-2-num)

Answer (score 1):

This is (semi)combinatoric problem.

For example imagine 4-digit number :

We start to find all numbers with one zero.

At first position (from left to right), you can use numbers from 1-9, then 1-9, then 1-9 and then there will be 0, so there is no other option.

its 9*9*9 possibilities.

And that zero can be in three positions.

Then we have to find all 4-digit numbers with two zeroes.

We can use Binomial coefficient where `(n k)` in our case will be : `n=number of digits - 1`, `k = number of zeroes` and then you multiply it by 9*9, because thats all possibilities of other numbers.

---

I have to go now, so I cant finish it for any possible number, but for given number of digits, this shold be working :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(numberZeroes(2));
}

public static int numberZeroes(int digits) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= digits - 1; i++) {
        result += binomial(digits - 1, i) * Math.pow(9, digits - i);                        
    }

    return result+1;
}

public static int binomial(final int N, final int K) {
    BigInteger ret = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int k = 0; k < K; k++) {
        ret = ret.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(N - k))
                .divide(BigInteger.valueOf(k + 1));
    }
    return ret.intValue();
}
```

Comment: That is easy if N = 99, 999, 9999 etc. But for an arbitrary N, say 3450, it's going to be difficult to implement that way.

Comment: Actually not that much, but you have to think about it, its not just "booom" and I have it. 

For 3450, you do it for 2999, which is trivial.

Then you have only 450, so you do it for 399

Then you have only 50, so you do it for 49

And then only 50 remains and thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using strings and regex, it would be a lot faster to keep dividing by 10 - for example:

```
int i = 96;
int firstDigit = i / 10;
int secondDigit = i - firstDigit * 10;
```

For arbitrarily large numbers, you just need to replace that by a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm calculates the number of zeros until 1000000000 in 20 seconds. I hope it helps.

```
int count = 0;
int n = 1000000000;
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    int m= i;
    do {
        if (m % 10 == 0)
            ++count;

        m = m / 10;
    } while (m > 0);
}
System.out.println("count = " + count);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int n = 1000000;
int count  = 0 ;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("0+");

for(int i = 0; i <= n ; i++ ) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(String.valueOf(i));
    while (m.find()) {
        count += m.group().length();
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```